# Get the image url inside Javascript with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml, screen-scraping

I am trying the get the product image from the page below, using Python and BeautifulSoup. The image is inside javascript. I am using lxml. I have created a simplified version of my code to focus on the image only.

The image url I am after is https://lapa.co.za/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/image/700x700/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/l/e/learn_to_read_l3_b05_tippie_fish_cover.jpg

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148'
}
testlink = 'https://lapa.co.za/kinder-en-tienerboeke/leer-my-lees-vlak-1-grootboek-9-tippie-en-die-vis'

r = requests.get(testlink, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

title = soup.find('h1', class_='page-title').text.strip()
images = soup.find('div', class_='product-img-column')

# html_data = requests.get(testlink).text
# data = json.loads(re.search(r'window.INITIAL_REDUX_STATE=(\{.*?\});', html_data))

print(images)
```

Comment: you can't, you need some thing that renders the javascript look in to webdrivers, I usually go for selenium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json is in the `<script>` tags. Just need to pull that out.

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148'
}
testlink = 'https://lapa.co.za/kinder-en-tienerboeke/leer-my-lees-vlak-1-grootboek-9-tippie-en-die-vis'

r = requests.get(testlink, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

title = soup.find('h1', class_='page-title').text.strip()
images = soup.find('div', class_='product-img-column')

script = images.find('script', {'type':'text/x-magento-init'})

jsonStr = re.search(r'<script type=\"text/x-magento-init\">(.*)</script>', str(script), re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL).group(1)
data = json.loads(jsonStr)

image_data = data['[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]']['mage/gallery/gallery']['data'][0]
image_url = image_data['full']

# OR 
#image_url = image_data['img']

print(image_url)
```

**Output:**

```
print(image_url)
https://lapa.co.za/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/image/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/9/7/9780799377347_1.jpg
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. One more thing, How would one get only the image name, as appose to the full url?

Comment: This produce the image name: image_name = (basename(image_url)) But how do I get the extension then?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I wanted to be able to split finename.jpg to "filename" and ".jpg"  I manage with this: image_name, image_extension = os.path.splitext(image_url)

Comment: you probably want this instead: `image_name, image_extension = image_url.split('/')[-1].split('.')` will give you `['9780799377347_1', 'jpg']` rather than the `https://` and the full domain